# How to set a breakpoint conditionally on a variable for a particular value in Netbeans?

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans

I know that we can place a breakpoint on a line conditionally by Right Click on breakpoint->Properties->Condition . But I don't know the exact syntax. Let's say for the following line

```
function(name,age);
```

I want to break on the line, only when "name" is equal to "XYZ". I tried to put condition like name="XYZ" and name=="XYZ". It does not help. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the netbeans FAQ. It is well documented how to set conditonal breakpints: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqDebuggingConditionalBreakpoints

In your case, you have to set `name.equals("XYZ")`

Comment: This link is now dead.